# Facebook app authentication

Tags: php, facebook

I made a fb PHP app sample and let my friend to use that. I expected him seeing an app authorization dialog.  But The error message "An error occurred. Please try again later" message had been appeared instead.
We got same result even if we use a sample program in FB SDK for PHP.

He could use the app after I added him as a tester on the app's setting page on Facebook.
But he's got same error message after I removed him on the setting page.
I (administrator of the app on the Facebook app's setting) haven't seen error message on my app.

I have been searching for the solution. I have checked followings.

1. The App's settings; app ID, site URL, canvas URL and app Domain are supposed to be correct.(Otherwise I would not have used the app)
2. Sandbox mode is disabled.

Please suggest me to let him use the app without adding him on the settings page.
Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting. Can you please edit your question and add the code you are using? Are you using a Server-Side or Client-Side flow? At what point does your friend get this error message? Do you set the channelUrl in the *FB.init* call?

Comment: Thanks you guys for answering. I was using a server side auth code that is example.php in Facebook sdk sample code.

Afterall, I get another app ID. I really don't know why/how, but my app started working. We didn't have any problems, my friend doesn't see any error message so far.

I suppose that settings are same, canvas URL is same, only differences are  app id and secret code. I really don't get it though. And The solution I found is kinda useless. But I let you know just in case.
@HARRY I am using a cheap web hosting service(5USD a month, incl.PHP MySQL and shared SSL)

Answer (score 0):

What hosting have you been using.. for your app and how do you know work out https url

I had the same issue when i tried using my app with facebook.com/socialserver for free https service, in that case i had tried my app first under me then completely under my friend administration and then again back to me .

Finally, i had to stop thinking about the free service and switch to the ads version of the service..